# _.memoize does not increase performance

Tags: javascript, node.js, underscore.js, lodash, memoization

Consider the finding nth Fibonacci number. The raw function `fib(32)` and `_.memoize(fib)(32)` take the same time.

```js
function fib(num) {
    if (num <= 1) return 1;
    return fib(num - 1) + fib(num - 2);
}

// slow
console.time('with memo')
_.memoize(fib)(32)
console.timeEnd('with memo')

// slow
console.time('no memo')
fib(32)
console.timeEnd('no memo')
```

You'll see both take roughly the same time. **No performance improvement.** Is there a way to alter the `memoize` function to create a true memoization that's equivalent to implementing memoization inside `fib` itself? Aka, I want the performance to the same as:

```js
// true memoization, actual performance improvement
// very fast!
cache = {}
function fib(n) {
    if (!cache[n]){
        if (n <= 1) cache[n] = 1;
        else cache[n] = fib(n - 1) + fib(n - 2);
    }
    return cache[n]
}
```

Answer (score 1):

It's not going to be faster the first time you run it. Memoization only gives you the benefits on subsequent executions.

```
function fib(num) {
    if (num <= 1) return 1;
    return fib(num - 1) + fib(num - 2);
}

const fibmem = _.memoize(fib);

fibmem(32);
console.time('with memo')
fibmem(32);
console.timeEnd('with memo')

fib(32);
console.time('no memo')
fib(32)
console.timeEnd('no memo')
```

This gave me:

```
with memo: 0.0732421875ms
no memo: 25.131103515625ms
```

Comment: is there a way to for `memoize` to actually modify the function to achieve optimal performance boost?

Comment: That's exactly what was done here - the `fibmem` function is a modified function that does give you a speed boost after the first time it is ran (with the same argument).